# Change default installation folder for ClickOnce application

Tags: clickonce

Is it possible to change the default installation folder of a ClickOnce application from C:\Users<user-name>\AppData to some other local drive H:?  This local drive does not have any restrictions or permission issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. ClickOnce install the application in a user's AppData folder , you should use MSI or some other installer technology

[MSDN Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84b5ed72-2406-4518-97e7-f7c6cf7132a7/how-to-control-the-location-of-clickonce-installation?forum=winformssetup)